# TStringList ValueFromIndex not working in PascalScript

Tags: delphi, freepascal, pascalscript

I'm trying to use TStrings.ValueFromIndex (which works in FreePascal and Delphi) in a PascalScript function, but it doesn't work, the compiler returns:

> Unknown identifier 'GETVALUEFROMINDEX'

I'm using it well?
Is this functionality available in PascalScript?
 if not, is there any easy way to do that?

THE CODE:

```
Function dummy(R: TStringList):String;
var
   i: Integer;
   RESULTv: string;
begin
   for i := 0 to ReqList.Count-1 do
     RESULTv := RESULTv + R.Names[i]+' -> '+ R.ValueFromIndex[i];
   dummy := RESULTv;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PascalScript's `TStrings` is a Delphi `TStrings`, but the `ValueFromIndex` method is not exposed by PascalScript. This can be seen by reading [`SIRegisterTStrings`](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/blob/master/Source/uPSC_classes.pas).

So, you need to make use of what is available. For instance the `Values` property:

```
RESULTv := RESULTv + R.Names[i] + ' -> ' + R.Values[R.Names[i]];
```

Or you might prefer to avoid some repetition with

```
Name := R.Names[i];
RESULTv := RESULTv + Name + ' -> ' + R.Values[Name];
```

This is rather inefficient, but unless you are going to parse the name/value pairs yourself, it's probably the best that you can do.

If you felt brave, you could compile PascalScript yourself, and add a call to `RegisterMethod` in [`SIRegisterTStrings`](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/blob/master/Source/uPSC_classes.pas) that registered `ValueFromIndex`.

Comment: However, using `Values[Name]` is not the equivalent of using `ValueFromIndex(i)` if the string list contains multiple entries with the same Name. So either recompile PS to expose `ValueFromIndex`, or write your own code that parses the raw `Strings[i]` value to remove its Name portion.

Comment: @Remy In my case there aren't duplicated Names so this simpler solution served.

Answer (score 5):

PascalScript is not the same as Delphi/FreePascal.  If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript) for PascalScript (specifically in `uPSC_classes.pas`), you will see that PascalScript merely wraps a native Delphi/FreePascal `TStringList`, but does not expose everything that Delphi/FreePascal actually implements in `TStringList`.  For instance, there is no wrapper exposed for the `ValueFromIndex` property.

**Update:**

Since PascalScript does not expose the `ValueFromIndex` property, you can write your own code that manually parses a String to remove its Name portion (if you don't patch PascalScript itself to add the missing property registration), eg:

```
Function GetValueFromIndex(R: TStringList; Index: Integer):String;
var
  S: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  S := R.Strings[Index];
  i := Pos('=', S);
  if I > 0 then
    ValueFromIndex := Copy(S, i+1, MaxInt)
  else
    ValueFromIndex := '';
end;

Function dummy(R: TStringList):String;
var
  i: Integer;
  RESULTv: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to ReqList.Count-1 do
    RESULTv := RESULTv + R.Names[i] + ' -> ' + GetValueFromIndex(R, i);
  dummy := RESULTv;
end;
```

Comment: but then why syntax error is thrown about missed method, not missed property itself ?

Comment: What is the actual error message? I am not a PS user, so I can only tell you what I see in PS's source code, and that is `ValueFromIndex` is not registered in PS's parser.

Comment: The workaround was already mentioned - either patch PS itself to add the missing registration, or else implement your own splitting logic in your PS script code.

Comment: @Remy Where in your answer is that mentioned?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I did not say it was in my answer. It is in your answer and in my comment to your answer.

Comment: You should answer the question.